# Disable autoclose in ng-select

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ngselect

I am using ng-select but when I click on an item, it closes automatically. I want it to stay open after selecting somethig.

what should I add to this code.

```
<ng-select [items]="items"
       bindLabel="name"
       bindValue="id"
       [multiple]="true"
       placeholder="Select categories"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedCategories">
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `closeOnSelect` to `false`

```
<ng-select [items]="items"
   bindLabel="name"
   bindValue="id"
   [multiple]="true"
   [closeOnSelect]="false"
   placeholder="Select categories"
   [(ngModel)]="selectedCategories">
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `isOpen` property:

```
<ng-select [items]="items"
       [isOpen]="true" // <--- This one
       bindLabel="name"
       bindValue="id"
       [multiple]="true"
       placeholder="Select categories"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedCategories">
</ng-select>
```